# How to make some calculation before sending object list to template on Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to make use of the function mis_puntos() it works perfect. what it does is go to the database and bring the current user's answers and compare them and give a +4 or +3 or 0 points  depending on the answer. But now i want to paginate a new query but i want to make use of this function, But Django only gives me a object list. I've been trying to create an array with the objects data but now giving a extra field called points so i can pass the ID value to the function and get returned both user data and total points per user but i don't know if this is going to struggle with the pagination.

The desired result is:

name  -     usuario  -   departamento  -    puntos

Ed           edd1          Accounting         10 Pts

What now i can handle to the template is, where puntos does not exist.

name  -     usuario  -   departamento  -    puntos

Ed           edd1          Accounting         Pts

Here is my function to get users points:

views.py

```
def mis_puntos(idempleado):

    query = '''SELECT
                quiniela_encuesta.id,
                quiniela_encuesta.golesEquipoA, 
                quiniela_encuesta.golesEquipoB, 
                quiniela_respuesta.equipoA, 
                quiniela_respuesta.equipoB

             FROM 
                quiniela_encuesta, 
                quiniela_respuesta

             WHERE
                quiniela_encuesta.id = quiniela_respuesta.encuesta_id
             AND
                quiniela_respuesta.empleado_id =  "%s" ''' % (idempleado)

    respuestas = respuesta.objects.raw(query)

    puntos_acumulados = 0
    partidos = 0

    for resultado in respuestas:

        if resultado.golesEquipoA == resultado.equipoA and resultado.golesEquipoB == resultado.equipoB:
            puntos_acumulados += 4
            partidos += 1
        else:

            if resultado.golesEquipoA == resultado.golesEquipoB and resultado.equipoA == resultado.equipoB:
                puntos_acumulados += 3
                partidos += 1

            else:

                if resultado.golesEquipoA < resultado.golesEquipoB and resultado.equipoA < resultado.equipoB:
                    puntos_acumulados += 3
                    partidos += 1

        if resultado.golesEquipoA > resultado.golesEquipoB and resultado.equipoA > resultado.equipoB:
            puntos_acumulados += 3
            partidos += 1

    args = {}
    args['puntos'] = puntos_acumulados
    args['partidos'] = partidos

    return args
```

now im showing you the function that gets handled to the view. that I'm mentioning needs to make use of the function mis_puntos but also return the users data.

```
def tablero_usuarios(request):

     if 'member_id' not in request.session:

         return HttpResponseRedirect('/empleado/login/')
     else:

        session_empleado = request.session['member_id']
        session_empresa = request.session['company_id']

        ayer = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        partidos_ayer = encuesta.objects.filter(
        fecha__startswith=ayer).order_by('-fecha')

        empleados = empleado.objects.get(id=session_empleado)

        datos_empresa = empresa.objects.get(id=session_empresa)
        # the variable below need to make use of mis_puntos() but return the data also not just the points.
        usuarios_tablero = empleado.objects.filter(empresa=session_empresa)

        args = {}
        args['empleado'] = empleados
        args['datos_empresa'] = datos_empresa
        args['datos_partidos'] = mis_puntos(session_empleado)
        args['partidos_ayer'] = partidos_ayer
        args['ranking'] = ranking(session_empresa)
        args['fecha_now'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        args['fecha_ayer'] = ayer
        args['usuarios_tablero'] = usuarios_tablero
        args.update(csrf(request))

    return render(request, 'quiniela/estadisticas.html', args)
```

My template:

```
<div id="table">

            <div class="row">
              <span class="cell row-style-left width-2 text-float-right bottom title-row"><strong>Avatar</strong></span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular width-20 text-float-right bottom title-row"><strong>Nombre</strong></span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular width-5 text-float-right bottom title-row"><strong>Departamento</strong></span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular text-float-right bottom width-10 title-row"><strong>Usuario</strong></span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular text-float-right bottom width-5 title-row"><strong>Puntos</strong></span>

            </div>


            {% for usuario in usuarios_tablero %}

            <div class="row">
              <span class="cell  row-style-left text-float-right bottom width-2">
              <img src="/media/{{ usuario.avatar.medium}}" height="35" width="35">
              </span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular width-20  bottom">{{ usuario.nombre}}</span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular width-5  bottom">{{ usuario.departamento}}</span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular text-float-right bottom width-10">{{ usuario.usuario}}</span>
              <span class="cell row-style-regular text-float-right bottom width-5"><!-- Puntos shoud be here.--></span>

            </div>
            {% endfor %}



          </div>
```

models.py

```
class equipo(models.Model):

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
bandera = StdImageField(upload_to='bandera/%Y/%m/%d',
                        variations={
                        'large':(53,53, False),
                        'thumbnail': (70, 26, False)})

GRUPOS = (
    ('A', 'Grupo A'),
    ('B', 'Grupo B'),
    ('C', 'Gropo C'),
    ('D', 'Gropo D'),
    ('E', 'Gropo E'),
    ('F', 'Gropo F'),
    ('G', 'Gropo G'),
    ('H', 'Gropo H'),
)

grupo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRUPOS)

def banderaEquipo(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s">' % (self.bandera.thumbnail)

banderaEquipo.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class encuesta(models.Model):

equipoA = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoA')
golesEquipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
equipoB = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoB')
golesEquipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)

ETAPA = (
    ('1', 'Primera Etapa'),
    ('2', 'Octavos De Final'),
    ('3', 'Cuartos De Final'),
    ('4', 'Semifinal'),
    ('5', 'Final'),
    ('6', '3ra Posicion')
)

etapa = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ETAPA)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s Vs. %s" % (unicode(self.equipoA), unicode(self.equipoB))


class respuesta(models.Model):

encuesta = models.ForeignKey(encuesta)
empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
empleado = models.ForeignKey(empleado)
equipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
equipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s" % (unicode(self.encuesta))
```

Comment: Do not use string formatting to create SQL queries (you are doing it in the `mis_puntos` function, when you generate `query`). Doing so will expose your application to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use [parameterized queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw).

Comment: the parameter comes from a session not a raw data from HTTP

Comment: Sure, but your code might be refactored in the future (by you or someone else), and you could end up being exposed. Or maybe an attacker find a way to control what's in the session, which will —again — expose your app. There really is no reason not to use a parameterized query here. It's a one line change.

Comment: Ill do the change, thanks... but right now my issue is how to add a extra parameter that makes use of that function on the object list :) thanks.

Comment: you know how to do that query using filter??? on django? Because i did it raw because of that. :(

Comment: Right now I'm trying to: usuarios_tablero = empleado.objects.filter(empresa=session_empresa)

        for usuarios in usuarios_tablero:

            usuarios.puntos.add(mis_puntos(usuarios.id)) but seems not to work.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question, but I suspect you might want to use [annotation / aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: Could you provide the relevant `models.py` definitions?

Comment: I added the models.py to the question. just edited it

Comment: as im aware django does not support JOINS as is in this case. but i still focus on the question. How i can return a filter() but before i pass it to the template add a extra field with the points calculated using mis_puntos() function???